# Падает приложение java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, android

Собираю приложение через Usb отладку все ок . Но когда собираю Apk  приложение падает `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:` На одном и тоже физическом устройстве.
Такое началось после Migrate to  android x был до этого appcompat

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
  at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.loadDrawableFromDelegates (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.addDelegate (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .addDrawableToCache (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .addTintListToCache (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .createCacheKey (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .createTintFilter (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .get (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .getCachedDrawable (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .getDrawable (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .getPorterDuffColorFilter (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .getTintMode (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .installDefaultInflateDelegates (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .isVectorDrawable (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .onConfigurationChanged (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .onDrawableLoadedFromResources (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .setHooks (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .tintDrawable (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .tintDrawableUsingColorFilter (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.addDelegate (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .addDrawableToCache (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .addTintListToCache (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .createCacheKey (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .createTintFilter (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .get (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .getCachedDrawable (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .getDrawable (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .getPorterDuffColorFilter (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .getTintMode (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .installDefaultInflateDelegates (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .isVectorDrawable (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .onConfigurationChanged (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .onDrawableLoadedFromResources (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .setHooks (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .tintDrawable (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .tintDrawableUsingColorFilter (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.checkVectorDrawableSetup (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .getTintList (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.addDelegate (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .addDrawableToCache (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .addTintListToCache (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .createCacheKey (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .createTintFilter (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .get (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .getCachedDrawable (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .getDrawable (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .getPorterDuffColorFilter (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .getTintMode (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .installDefaultInflateDelegates (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .isVectorDrawable (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .onConfigurationChanged (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .onDrawableLoadedFromResources (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .setHooks (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .tintDrawable (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .tintDrawableUsingColorFilter (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.access$000 (AppCompatDrawableManager.java)
  or                     .getDrawable (AppCompatDrawableManager.java)
  or                     .getPorterDuffColorFilter (AppCompatDrawableManager.java)
  or                     .onConfigurationChanged (AppCompatDrawableManager.java)
  or                     .tintDrawable (AppCompatDrawableManager.java)
  at androidx.appcompat.widget.TintTypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize (TintTypedArray.java)
  or                     .getDrawableIfKnown (TintTypedArray.java)
  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.addContentView (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
  or                     .applyDayNight (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
  or                     .attachBaseContext (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
  or                     .attachToWindow (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
  or                     .callOnPanelClosed (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
  or                     .closePanel (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
  or                     .createView (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
  or                     .dispatchKeyEvent (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
  or                     .findMenuPanel (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
  or                     .findViewById (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
  or                     .getPanelState (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
  or                     .initializePanelContent (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
  or                     .onConfigurationChanged (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
  or                     .onCreate (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
  or                     .onKeyDown (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
  or                     .onMenuItemSelected (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
  or                     .onMenuModeChange (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
  or                     .onSubDecorInstalled (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
  or                     .openPanel (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
  or                     .performPanelShortcut (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
  or                     .reopenMenu (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
  or                     .setContentView (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
  or                     .setTitle (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
  or                     .shouldInheritContext (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
  or                     .startSupportActionMode (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate (AppCompatActivity.java)
  at dima113xxx.coin_calculator.Main2Activity.onCreate (Main2Activity.java)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6876)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1135)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3206)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3349)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100 (ActivityThread.java:221)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1794)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:158)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7225)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1230)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

////

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "dima113xxx.coin_calculator"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 66
        versionName "4.4.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled  true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0-alpha02', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha04'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:18.1.1'
    implementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-3'
}




apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

////

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "dima113xxx.coin_calculator"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 66
        versionName "4.4.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled  true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0-alpha02', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha04'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:18.1.1'
    implementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-3'
}




apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: apk с каким флэйвором собираете? покажите градл тот что в модуле

Comment: Eugene Zaychenko, я  добавил в описание

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже что проблема в прогуарде, измените

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled  true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

на

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled  false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

если соберется и не будет ошибок после установки апк то проблема в Proguard - надо прописать правила и вернуть как было.

Comment: Черт побери - вы правы так все работает ( вот так цирк  так зашифровывает что сам потом работать не может  ) что дальше делать что мне нужно изменить ??! Большое спасибо  за помощь !!!!

Comment: Надо настроить Прогуард или отключить его. Возможно после перехода на андроидХ появились различия с тем что в правилах и в реальности. Нужно правильно прописать правила. Начините с малого http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/proguard.php почитайте про Прогуард